# This algo run only on internet explorer why?

Tags: database, jsp

This algo is created by me, algo is used to store images into database using jsp. Why does this algo run only on Internet Explorer?

**insert.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <form name="contact" action="first.jsp" method="post">
    First name:
    <input type=text name="sfname" value=""/><br>
    Insert Image:
    <input type=file name="sphoto" value=""/>
    <br>
    <button type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**first.jsp**

```
    first.jsp
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <%@ page import="java.sql.*"%>
    <%@ page import="java.io.*"%>

    <%
    try{  
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/snt","root","passoword");

    PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("insert into imgtable(name,photo) values(?,?)");  
     String z=request.getParameter("sfname");
    ps.setString(1," " +z+"  ");  
    String zz=request.getParameter("sphoto");
    String replaceString=zz.replace(":",":\\");  

    FileInputStream fin=new FileInputStream(""+replaceString+"");  
    ps.setBinaryStream(2,fin,fin.available());  
    int i=ps.executeUpdate();  
    out.println(i+" records affected");  

    if(i==1)
    {
        response.sendRedirect("insert.jsp");    
    }
    con.close();  
    }catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();} 

    //
    %>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Database table**

```
create database snt
 use snt

 drop table imgtable
create table imgtable(
id int auto_increment primary key,
name text,
photo longblob
);
```

Comment: Can you further explain what you mean by it only running with Explorer?

Comment: I can tell you that regardless what browser you use `request.getParameter("sphoto")` will always return `null` because you cannot read a file that way. You have to use `request.getPart("sphoto")` or Apache Commons File Upload Library.  And `getPart` will only work on Tomcat 6 or higher, not Tomcat 5 (meaning you have to use the Apache library with Tomcat 5 and lower).

Comment: i am saying that this algo works fine with internet explorer but not working with chrome and firefox why? @developerwjk

Comment: I'm saying that's not really possible. Perhaps if you explained what exactly is and is not working that would clarify.